# Optimizing min & max query in nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, query-optimization

I have a following query in nHibernate. The idea is to get first and last measurement time of certain data group.

```
var measurements = _session.Query<Measurement>()
                           .Where(x => categories.Contains(x.CategoryId));
first = measurements.Min(o => o.StartTime);
last = measurements.Max(o => o.StartTime);
```

The SQL Server Profiler gives following output:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select cast(min(measuremen0_.StartTime) as DATETIME) as col_0_0_ from Measurement measuremen0_ where measuremen0_.Category in (@p0 , @p1)',N'@p0 int,@p1 int',@p0=7654321,@p1=3324673

exec sp_executesql N'select cast(max(measuremen0_.StartTime) as DATETIME) as col_0_0_ from Measurement measuremen0_ where measuremen0_.Category in (@p0 , @p1)',N'@p0 int,@p1 int',@p0=7654321,@p1=3324673
```

Can I somehow optimize this **without using HQL**, so that it would create only **one** request to the database server?

Comment: Why no HQL? Is it against your religion or something?

Comment: For me HQL is almost same as writing SQL and I think you lose readability, IntelliSense and the whole point of using ORM (which is mapping relations).

Comment: I have to admit that sometimes you have to do things in more low-level way (like HQL). Maybe this is that kind of case? But I would like to push people to think answer in some other way than HQL.

Comment: 1. HQL is not low level, it's object-oriented just like LINQ, but more flexible. 2. There are addons that get you HQL intellisense. 3. If Intellisense is THE reason why you use LINQ, maybe NH is not the best framework for you.

Comment: I think the question is sound and there is an answer without using HQL. Just because HQL is not desirable by the OP doesn't mean that he should abandon NHibernate entirely. I just feel you are being a tad harsh Diego.

Comment: HQL is not SQL. HQL queries your object model and is especially suited for these kind of things. When HQL is not readable how can your model be?

Comment: We can argue until the end of the world which is suitable and what is not, but in our project HQL would add another syntax / technology and therefore increase the learning curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you take a look at the [Future Queries](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/01/nhibernate-and-future-queries/)? I think it works for linq queries as well.

Comment: I will check it out and let you know can it be some how combined with max and min

Comment: Futures will save you a roundtrip to the database but not save you a query. Should not matter.